# Clearing QgsSpinBox without manually toggling focus

Tags: pyqgis

Consider this `QgsSpinBox` in a dialog:

[image]

```
def clear():
    qgsspinbox.clear()
def clear_and_focus():
    qgsspinbox.clear()
    qgsspinbox.setFocus(True)
def print_is_null():
    print(qgsspinbox.lineEdit().isNull())
def set_to_clear_value():
    qgsspinbox.setValue(-2147483648)

dialog = QDialog()
button = QPushButton("Clear!")
button.clicked.connect(clear)
button1b = QPushButton("Clear + Focus!")
button1b.clicked.connect(clear_and_focus)
button1 = QPushButton("Set to Clear Value!")
button1.clicked.connect(set_to_clear_value)
button2 = QPushButton("Null?")
button2.clicked.connect(print_is_null)

qgsspinbox = QgsSpinBox()
qgsspinbox.setLineEditAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)
qgsspinbox.setRange(-2147483648, 2147483647)
#qgsspinbox.setClearValueMode(QgsSpinBox.ClearValueMode.CustomValue)  # set automatically if setClearValue is used
qgsspinbox.setClearValue(-2147483648, "NULL")  # this works ok, lets assume users never want that value...
qgsspinbox.clear()

other_widget_to_switch_focus = QLineEdit()
other_widget_to_switch_focus.setPlaceholderText("Click here to switch focus")

layout = QVBoxLayout()
layout.addWidget(qgsspinbox)
layout.addWidget(other_widget_to_switch_focus)
layout.addWidget(button)
layout.addWidget(button1b)
layout.addWidget(button1)
layout.addWidget(button2)
dialog.setLayout(layout)
other_widget_to_switch_focus.setFocus(True)

dialog.show()
```

If you press the "*Null?*" button, the state of `qgsspinbox.lineEdit().isNull()` will be printed. This should print `True` if the `QgsSpinBox` was cleared.

You can press the other buttons to:

- *Clear!* -> Clear the `QgsSpinBox`
- *Clear + Focus!* -> Clear the `QgsSpinBox` and focus it afterwards
- *Set to Clear Value!* -> Set the `QgsSpinBox`'s value to the same value that clearing would use (aka that is considered to be a "clear" value)

In theory all three buttons should put the `QgsSpinBox` in a state where its `QgsFilterLineEdit` `isNull()` returns `True`.

But a simple `.clear()` does not lead to that. Only if one focuses the `QgsSpinBox` afterwards, it will actually be nulled.

I want to be able to call `QgsSpinBox.clear()` without then having to fiddle with focus. That would confuse the user and add weird complexity. How do I properly clear a `QgsSpinBox` so that calling its `QgsFilterLineEdit.isNull()` afterwards does returns `True`?